# Angularjs Multidimensional array and two relative select boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a multidimensional array that holds the product names and versions.
I want to create an interface that lets the user select the product from a select box, and then the version number in the second select box. The second select box should only show the versions numbers of the product that the user selected in the first select box.

This is my mutidimensional array:

```
[Object]0: 
         name: "Product 1"
         versions: [Array]0:
                           number: "1.0"
                           number: "1.5.2"
        1: 
         name: "Product 2"
         versions: [Array]0:
                           number: "0.0"
                           number: "0.5"
```

The user has the option to choose multiple products, so I created an array to hold the users selection.

my controller is setup like this:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.products = [{id: 1, name: '', versions: []}];

  $scope.packages = [];
  $scope.packages[0] = { id: 1, name: 'Product 1', versions: [{number: 1.0}, {number: 1.5}, {number: 2.0}]};
  $scope.packages[1] = { id: 2, name: 'Product 2', versions: [{number: 0.1}, {number: 0.2}, {number: 0.3}]};

    $scope.addProduct = function(){
    var id = $scope.products.length + 1;
    $scope.products.push({id: id, name: "", version: []});

  };
});
```

And the select boxes are setup like this with angularjs:

```
    <div  ng-repeat="product in products">
       <label>Product</label>
       <select ng-model="product.product" ng-options="package.name for package in packages" class="form-control"></select>

       <label>Version</label>
       <select ng-model="product.versions" ng-options="version.number for version in product.versions" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
<button ng-click="addProduct()">Add Product</button>
```

What I tried to do was setup the ng-options to select the versions object of the current product. But this doesn't work.

I created a jsFiddle of what I currently have:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkyu4rjq/

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to link the version select box with the product selected.

TIA

Comment: Is this something like what you're trying to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005042/cascading-dropdown-angularjs-ng-option-object-error/31025747#31025747

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I'm not really keeping track of which version chosen for each product I fixed your relative select options.

You can find a `solution` [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zB6FHuDKFUTkOGGGK0kF?p=preview). This should get you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

I missed something very simple.

In the version select box binding I should of used `version.number for version in product.product.versions` instead of `version.number for version in product.versions`

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkyu4rjq/2/

Comment: This was the problem of the version numbers indeed... but I still find your code kind of weird. The first ng-repeat could become a very expensive render... your form is encapsulated within thus on every add an extra form will have to be rendered, which has to iterate over the exact same package array in order to add to the first list anyway.