# Angular.js cascading dropdown - mapping two models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently am struggling with mapping the value of a cascading dropdown -
with data driven by a tree constructed by an angular controller - to a primitive
string for posting back to a MVC controller.

I have a tree of data to populate the cascading dropdown, with the basic format of

```
public class Series
{    
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Depth> Depths { get; set; }
}

public class Depth
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Which is then mapped using angular to the output, which is an MVC type model:

```
public class LineItemViewModel
{
    public string Series { get; set; }
    public double Depth { get; set; }
}
```

Using an angular controller, where joistGroup is a list of series populated on controller creation.

HTML:

```
<div class="initialRow row"
     ng-repeat="joist in floor.Joists">
    <select name="series" class="form-control" 
            data-ng-model="series"
            data-ng-options="s as s.Text for s in joistGroup.Series"
            data-ng-change="joist.Series = series.Text">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <select name="depth" class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="depth"
            data-ng-options="d as d.Text for d in series.Depths"
            data-ng-change="joist.Depth = depth.Value;"
            data-rule-required="true">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Angular controller:

```
var app = angular.module('MaterialListModule', []);
app.controller('MaterialListController', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.getMaterialList = function() {
        $http.get('url for get call')
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Model = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.getProducts = function (productSource) {   
        $http.get('url for get')
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.allItems = data;
            $scope.joistGroup = $filter('filter')($scope.allItems, { Text: 'Joists' }, true)[0];
        }).finally(function() {
            $scope.getMaterialList();
        });
    }

    $scope.getProducts("All");
});
```

Currently I am using ng-change to trigger an update of the primitive for posting back
to the MVC controller, but as this is both a create and edit page this doesn't work
for when I already have a selected series. I am thinking I can get it working by ng-init
but haven't had any success.

Can anyone point me in the direction of best practices to map a complex model for
cascading dropdowns to a primitive and back?

Comment: Can you show us what you have in your angular controller?

Comment: Added it. The data is driven by the MVC controller so there is quite a bit of complication around that.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if i'm understanding your question - you have a 'complex' object that is used to drive the drop downs, however you need to send back a primitive to update your database/store? Is that the gist of it?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The object that drives the dropdowns contains a list of valid options for the child, and I just need to send back a primitive for the database.

Comment: I couldn't find a better way to phrase it, so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You know you can link one select model to the other?  This answer isn't on point but you can see in the demo how each selection populates the next select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005042/cascading-dropdown-angularjs-ng-option-object-error/31025747#31025747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your `ng-change` inline, hook it up to a function. In that function, you can then access the 'complex object' and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
$scope.depthChange = function() {
   $scope.myPrimitive = $scope.depth.Value;
   //Do something with primitive
}
```

Also, when you have something already selected, on initialisation/retrieval of the data, just set the `$scope.depth` to the complex object that should be selected