# Create Html Elements With Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have a seemingly simple problem - I have a list of locations, which have sublocations, which have sublocations, and so on. The first location (level 1) is picked from a drop down.

The goal is to have ANOTHER drop down appear under the first drop down (if) the selected location has sublocations. There can be an infinite number of dropdowns. What's the best way to handle creating these new dropdowns with angular?

The kicker? If possible, I would like to be able to bind these dropdowns with ng-model. I don't even know where to start on this one. Almost tempted to try an ng-repeat or something.

Comment: Have a go and then edit your question to include your attempt, preferably with a link to a demo on plunker. It will be much easier to help you and you will get much better responses.

Comment: In programming there can be nothing unlimited but the result of division by zero. Where do you take you data from?

Comment: There can be many solutions and they all are arguable, because the question is too vast. However I would propose to create a list of items (each will contain name and list of sub-locations) and display them using `ng-repeat`. This way you can populate dynamic number of dropdowns

Comment: As suggested, try it first.  If you get stuck, post some code.  You can take a look at the demo in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005042/cascading-dropdown-angularjs-ng-option-object-error/31025747#31025747) as a pattern for your approach.  That will help with the ng-model part of your question, as for the rest, I think the others gave you some hints there already (nothing is infinite and try ng-repeat).